# How to load external page/content into a DIV

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Here's my problem:

I have do create a menu/list of actions (which would be easier if made with a control that accepts a DataSource, like listview or even Gridview with templated collumns).

Each of this actions need a specific form to be exectuted, and I've already created all these forms in separated aspx pages.

The question is: what would be the best way to load these pages/forms inside a div when I select any action in the list, without making a page refresh or using iframes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (as I've understood your actions are links to your forms):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.yourActionClass').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url, function(response) {
            $('div#yourDivForForm').html(response);
        });
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.yourActionClass').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('div#yourDivForForm').load(url);
    });
});
```

**ADDED:**

If you are returning "full" ASPX pages with forms:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.yourActionClass').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $.get(url, function(response) {
            var page = $(response);
            var form = $('form', page);
            $('div#yourDivForForm').prepend(form);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: hi eugene.. thanks for the help.

The fact is that i'm not used to jquery at all... in your last sample (for loading full pages) how would I load one different page (form) for each service?

Comment: In the last sample I'm assuming that the "list of actions" is a list of links with urls (<a href="/page_url">An action</a>). But the example could be modified if your list contains buttons

Comment: hey @eu-ge-ne The first two examples always worked fine for me.. but they do not load when I call an APSX page with forms... BUT the last code you added isn't working neither... Would you help me again?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what Ajax is for.
First create a  XMLHttpObject and use it to open a url

﻿

```
var req;

    function loadXMLDoc(url) {
    // branch for native XMLHttpRequest object
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
        req.open("GET", url);
        req.send(null);
        // branch for IE/Windows ActiveX version
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        if (req) {
            req.onreadystatechange = processReqChange;
            req.open("GET", url);
            req.send();
        }
    }

}
```

The response will come back through the processReqChange event handler.

```
function processReqChange() {
    // only if req shows "complete"
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
        // only if "OK"
        if (req.status == 200) {
            // process the result
            document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = req.responseText;
        } else {
            alert("There was a problem retrieving the XML data:\n" + req.statusText);
        }
    }
}
```

Just replace "mydiv" with the id of the div you want to fill.

Peter